# How can I condense the values in an array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array of elements, I need to change elements at the beginning of an array and I'm using the foreach.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
            [1] => address
            [2] => detail
            [3] => name
            [4] => family
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
            [1] => address
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
            [1] => address
            [2] => detail
            [3] => name
        )

)
```

I want this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user.address.detail.name
            [1] => family
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
            [1] => address
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user.address.detail
            [1] => name
        )

)
```

this is my code but it seems it's not working.

```
    $firstTemp = "";
    foreach ($temps as $row => $temp) {
        if (count($temp) > 2) {
            foreach ($temp as $k => $content) {

                $firstTemp .= $content . '.';
                $endTemp = end($temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better and more concise way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the result you currently get? Do you get an error of any kind?

Comment: What's the pattern? Should you you always combine all values into a dot separated string but leave the last "as is" or is there some other pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some modification in your snippet to make it work,

```
$result    = [];
foreach ($temps as $row => $temp) {
    if (count($temp) > 2) {
        // I am taking a slice of the array except for last element and imploding it with `.`
        // then I am fetching the last element of an array
        //  creating an array and pushing it into the result variable
        $result[] = [implode(".", array_slice($temp, 0, count($temp) - 1)), end($temp)];
    }else{
        $result[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

I am imploding all the elements except last element using [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).
`end` I used to fetch the last element of an array.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CautX).

**EDIT 1**
One more way to achieve the same,

```
$result    = [];
foreach ($temps as $row => $temp) {
    if (count($temp) > 2) {
        // except last elements
        $result[] = [implode(".", array_slice($temp, 0, -1)), end($temp)];
    }else{
        $result[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/daIjU).

**EDIT 2**

```
$result    = [];
foreach ($temps as $row => $temp) {
    $result[] = (count($temp) > 2 ? [implode(".", array_slice($temp, 0, -1)), end($temp)] : $temp);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tdQlK).

**EDIT 3**

```
$result = array_map(function($temp){
    return (count($temp) > 2 ? [implode(".", array_slice($temp, 0, -1)), end($temp)] : $temp);
},$temps);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vb5XW).

**EDIT 4**: Without condition

```
$result = array_map(function($temp){
    return [implode(".",array_slice($temp,0,-1)),array_pop($temp)];
},$temps);
```

**EDIT 5**

```
$result = array_map(function($temp){
    return [implode(".",array_slice($temp,0,-1)),end($temp)];
},$temps);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oIVQB).

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user.address.detail.name
            [1] => family
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user
            [1] => address
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user.address.detail
            [1] => name
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `pull the last element` and `implode()` rest of the element from array Like:

```
$formatted = [];

foreach($temps as $arr) {

    if(count($arr) == 0){
       return;
    }

     $last = array_pop($arr);

    if(count($arr) > 0) //check if array not empty.
       $formatted[] = [implode(".", $arr), $last];
    else
       $formatted[] = [$last];   
}
```

Comment: @Maryam does this help?

Comment: Nice one. But `$arr` can be empty after `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    [
        'user',
        'address',
        'detail',
        'name',
        'family',
    ], [
        'user',
        'address',
    ], [
        'user',
        'address',
        'detail',
        'name',
        'family',
    ]
];

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    $last = array_pop($item);

    return [implode('.', $item), $last];
}, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using two `foreach` structures. For example:

```php
$result = array_map(function (&$temp) {
  $last = array_pop($temp);
  $first = implode('.', $temp);

  return [$first, $last];
}, $temps);
```